# How to change the color of the text inside a View?

Tags: android

I have some Views in my Activity that I inflate and populate at runtime.

The View itself is a RelativeLayout to which I add at runtime several TextViews.

When the View is selected I change the color of the background (and that is easy).

Now I need to change the color of all the TextViews inside the View.

Please how do I do that?

Consider that I do not have a reference to the TextViews themselves, since they are created at runtime, nor do I know how many are in there.

Comment: You don't have to add "Android:" to your titles, you've already provided the tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Consider that I do not have a reference to the TextViews themselves

Since you "add at runtime several TextViews", you are certainly welcome to "have a reference to the TextViews themselves". Add them to some sort of collection (e.g., `ArrayList<TextView>`) at the time when you "add at runtime", then iterate over the collection to change their color.

Comment: thanks a lot Mark! How unfortunate :-((( this adds a lot of complexity ! But if it is the only solution... :-(((

Answer (score 1):

You can do this another way:

Iterate over all children of the RelativeLayout (which you have a reference to):

```
for (int i = 0; i < mRelativeLayout.getChildCount(); i++) {
    if (mRelativeLayout.getChildAt(i) instanceof TextView) {

        // Set text color
        ((TextView)(rl.getChildAt(i))).setTextColor(Color.RED);
    }
}
```

Be careful about `mRelativeLayout.get(i) instanceof TextView`. This will return `true` for all Views returned by `mRelativeLayout.getChildAt(i)` **that are** subclasses of TextView. For example, if you have a Button inside `mRelativeLayout`, `instanceof` will return `true` since Button extends TextView. To avoid this, use:

```
if (mRelativeLayout.getChildAt(i) instanceof TextView && 
                                !(mRelativeLayout.getChildAt(i) instanceof Button))
```